# Pyspark - filter out multiple rows based on a condition in one row

Tags: python, sql, database, pyspark

I have a table like so:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Id  |  Value   | Some Other Columns Here
| 0   |  5       |
| 0   |  4       |
| 0   |  0       |
| 1   |  3       |
| 2   |  1       |
| 2   |  8       |
| 3   |  -4      |
--------------------------------------------
```

I would like to remove all IDs which have any Value <= 0, so the result would be:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Id  |  Value   | Some Other Columns Here
| 1   |  3       |
| 2   |  1       |
| 2   |  8       |
--------------------------------------------
```

I tried doing this by filtering to only rows with Value<=0, selecting the distinct IDs from this, converting that to a list, and then removing any rows in the original table that have an ID in that list using `df.filter(~df.Id.isin(mylist))`

However, I have a huge amount of data, and this ran out of memory making the list, so I need to come up with a pure pyspark solution.

Comment: Why id 0 are removed in your expected output? The values are greater than 0 right?

Comment: @Raghu because it has 1 row with `Value <= 0` (based on what i understood)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Gordon mentions, you may need a window for this, here is a pyspark version:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("Id")
(df.withColumn("flag",F.when(F.col("Value")<=0,0).otherwise(1))
   .withColumn("Min",F.min("flag").over(w)).filter(F.col("Min")!=0)
   .drop("flag","Min")).show()
```

---

```
+---+-----+
| Id|Value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    3|
|  2|    1|
|  2|    8|
+---+-----+
```

Brief summary of approach taken:

- Set a flag when `Value<=0` then `0` else `1
- get min over a partition of id (will return 0 if any of prev cond is
  met)
- filter only when this `Min` value is not 0

`

Answer (score 4):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(value) over (partition by id) as min_value
      from t
     ) t
where min_value > 0
```

Comment: your logic is better than mine, no need of a conditional reference when we can just take `min` of a partition to compare..